# Putting contents of a file on NSPasteboard using UTI not NSFileContentsPboardType?

Tags: cocoa, clipboard, nspasteboard, uti

I have rich-text file with a few images and text. In my Cocoa app I'm trying to put the contents of that file on the `NSDragPboard` so that the user can drag the *contents* into other applications (TextEdit, Mail, etc.).

One usecase is this: the rich-text file contains an email template and the user drags the contents into a new Mail message.

I tried this without success:

```
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
[pboard writeFileContents:filePath];
```

The Apple docs say this:

> *Writes the contents of the file
>   filename to the receiver and declares
>   the data to be of type
>   **NSFileContentsPboardType** and also of a
>   type appropriate for the file’s
>   extension (as returned by the
>   NSCreateFileContentsPboardType
>   function when passed the files
>   extension), if it has one.*

In the ClipboardViewer app I can see a few data types, one being `NXFileContentsPboardType`. However, apps such as Mail and TextEdit don't allow to drop that data type.

When I copy the rich-text content to the clipboard by hand (Control+C), I see all the different data types I want:

- `public.rtf`
- `public.utf8-plain-text`
- `NSStringPboardType`
- ...

So how can I do that programmatically myself? Do I have to figure out all the various UTI types and set the according data? I thought that's what `[pboard writeFileContents:path]` was for...

Thanks, Mark.

**EDIT:**

Making progress... This works for `.rtf` files, but not for `.txt` files:

```
NSString *uti = // helper code to get UTI from NSURL resource key...
NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:uti] owner:nil];
[pboard setData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] forType:uti];
```

For `.txt` files the data type on the pasteboard is `public.text`. However, TextEdit and Mail.app won't allow dropping that type. `public.rtf` in case of rich text works fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's not possible to add file contents to the pasteboard and have the content types be detected automatically.

It turns out that putting RTF/RTFD file contents on the pasteboard is as simple as:

```
NSAttributedString *contents = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithPath:filePath documentAttributes:NULL];
// This sets the correct type automatically:
[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:contents]];
[contents release];
```